# urllib.request.urlretrieve not working over HTTP websites

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib, urllib3

urllib.request.urlretrieve not working over HTTP websites, however the same is able to save url over HTTPS websites.

```
import urllib.request

abc="http://www.google.com"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(abc,"C:\\Users\\kj\\downloads\\abc.html")
```

I'm getting the following error:

> [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

When i use "https://www.google.com", the code is working. I am currently working on a website which is not a secured website (http), and this code is not working on them.

I have read few threads on this portal, but could not find a solution.

i am using python 3.6.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.google.com triggers a redirection to https://www.google.com . Apparently urllib does not follow this redirection and thus never retrieves any data.

Comment: @leonardo - I am able to save Http urls on a VM or a machine based in India. Not able to save http url with this code when I am running it on VM based in US. The error mentions network problems, can it be fixed with proxies or firewall settings??